# Does AWS RDS support two way replication with local MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, database-replication

I would like to sync the local MySQL database to Amazon RDS MySQL database. I found a solution for EC2 to RDS but not for Local Database to RDS.

I built a database including 12 tables which all I want to get backup them to cloud periodically or automatically.
I do not want to run EC2 server since I need only MySQL database to get backup on cloud.

I need a solution like Microsoft Database Sync Agent. Whenever changes detected in Local Database, it should be synced to the cloud database. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html):

> AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) is a cloud service that makes it easy to migrate relational databases, data warehouses, NoSQL databases, and other types of data stores. You can use AWS DMS to migrate your data into the AWS Cloud, between on-premises instances (through an AWS Cloud setup), or between combinations of cloud and on-premises setups.
>
> With AWS DMS, you can perform one-time migrations, and **you can replicate ongoing changes to keep sources and targets in sync**.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following below steps.

- Make a replica of local server to RDS.
- Enable Query logging in local Database
- Create a cron job which will process logging queries and it will execute queries on RDS instance in same order.

To generate a replica to RDS you can follow below steps.

You can't replicate your local database to RDS directly. Your need to dump you data and then after you can import it on RDS.

Instead of generating a dump file you can directly import data into RDS using below command.

```
mysqldump db_name | mysql -h 'other_hostname' db_name
```

You can find our more about this over here.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html

Also first import tables & it's data then after import your triggers, routines & events. If you import together then there is a chances to get conflict and you job will be terminated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see this is a manual method. I think I need to synchronize the local database to RDS manually. May I know the method you describe above supports automatically synchronization.

Comment: Yes, It will. As here all queries which will be executed locally, that will be executed on RDS instance in the same order.